# Why do I get an HResult=-2146233088 JsonReaderException with this code?

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got this code to try to open a .json file and read it:

```
[Route("{unit}/{begindate}")]
public string Get(string unit, string begindate)
{
    string _unit = unit;
    string _begindate = String.Format("{0}01", PlatypusWebReportsConstsAndUtils.HyphenizeYYYYMM(begindate));           
    string appDataFolder = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/");
    // semi-hardcoded file name for now
    string jsonFilename = string.Format("PoisonToe_{0}_{1}.json", _unit, _begindate);
    string fullPath = Path.Combine(appDataFolder, jsonFilename);
    JObject platypusComplianceJson = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(fullPath));
    . . .
```

On the last line, I get:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException was unhandled by user code
> HResult=-2146233088
> Message=Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object:

Based on what I read [here](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadJson.htm), I thought this would be the way to do it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does `File.ReadAllText` return?

Comment: Can you also check the `fullPath` that is being returned and make sure it is exactly what you want? If that is good, I suggest the above as well

Comment: What is the rest of the message? It should be telling you what is not an object. A typical thing that's not an object would the start of an array (i.e. StartArray token). Did you mean to use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` instead? or maybe `JArray.Parse`?

Comment: @JamesKirsch: It's the exact same fullPath I use to store the file in the first place. I'll try a simple "File.ReadAllText" Monday.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's difficult to give a better answer without the information requested in comments, but this means, as it suggests, that the current token isn't the start of an object.

Just to be clear, we're talking about "object" in the JSON vocabulary, and *not* in the C#/OOP vocabulary sense.

It sounds like what's going on here is something like the non-JSON `bool.Parse("1")`. Yes, `"1"` is valid input to a parse method (`int.Parse`, for instance), but this is the wrong method.

The simple trick (warning: Band-Aid fix) is to switch to `JToken.Parse`. `JToken` is a polymorphic parent of `JObject`, `JArray`, `JValue`, and the lot, so its parse is able to handle a lot more types of unstructured input.

Before you do that, as I'm sure you know, you should of course double-check your contracts and the file, to see which is wrong. There's certainly no good in successfully parsing a `JArray` that you then use as a `JObject`.

For good measure, a few file texts that would cause this error are:

- (empty file)
- `[{ "test": "val" }]` (array)
- `"test"` (string)
- `null`

These should all be valid inputs to `JToken.Parse`, I believe, but they'd all give this error on `JObject.Parse`, because they aren't objects. You need something like:

- `{ "test": "val" }`
- `{ "test": { "val": 2 } }`

Or something to that effect.

---

Back on my OOP point, a `JObject` isn't the elementary base type of everything in JSON.net, but `JToken` is. So even though you could say,

```
object i = new int[0];
```

in C#, you can't say,

```
JObject i = JObject.Parse("[0, 0, 0]");
```

in JSON.net.