# C# JObject.Parse error

Tags: json, json.net

I'm getting the following exception:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException in Newtonsoft.Json.dll ("Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1."). Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll ("Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Here is the code:

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(verigetir(veri.getir(), "cari_ip_alma.php"));

public string verigetir(string veri, string sayfa)
{
    string postData;

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(server + sayfa);
    request.Method = "POST";
    postData = veri;
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    return reader.ReadToEnd();

    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
}

class parametreOlustur
{
    public string data;

    public void birlestir(string a, string b)
    {
        data += "&" + a + "=" + b;
    }

    public string getir()
    {
        return data;
    }
}
```

PHP Code :

https://shrib.com/?v=md#iT73qB_Lr250Uoh8CZbk

if i'm change php codes  $row= $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) fetchAll to Fetch , program is working but getting first data.

Comment: Formatting, Inlined the source code example

Comment: Can you include the input data being parsed? That may be where the problem is. Also, I notice that you're returning from `verigetir` before closing your streams. You should be getting a build warning on that...

Comment: Just i want to get all mssql table data

Comment: Your JSON root container is an array not an object.  See [Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34690581) for how to fix.  If you don't know in advance if your JSON represents an object or an array, see [JSON.NET: Why Use JToken--ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38211719/3744182) for how to fix.  To give you any specific help we need an [mcve] showing the JSON you are trying to parse.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question, you need to learn to use the [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) statement to dispose of disposables like `reader`, `dataStream` and `response`.

Comment: I fix my problem if rows bigger than 1 Jobject Doesn't working , i'm chagne Jobject to Jarray and my problem has fixed , thanks guys :)