# Why can I not parse this JSON string?

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to parse a JSONstring with a very simple snippet of code as follows

```
 string androidObject = "[{\"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"]," +
                                   "\"target\": {" +
                                   "\"namespace\": \"android_app\"," +
                                   "\"package_name\": \"xxx.demo\"," +
                                   "\"sha256_cert_fingerprints\":[\"xxx\"]" +
                                   "}" +
                                   "},{" +
                                   "\"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"]," +
                                   "\"target\": {" +
                                   "\"namespace\": \"android_app\"," +
                                   "\"package_name\": \"xxx.demo\"," +
                                   "\"sha256_cert_fingerprints\":[\"xxx\"]" +
                                   "}" +
                                   "}]";

            return new OkObjectResult(JObject.Parse(androidObject));
```

But it fails in the JObject.Parse saying its not a valid object, but if I log the output and pastes it into a JSON validator it is valid so I am confused as to why it does not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: *JObject.Parse saying its not a valid object* because it is a **JSON array** not a JSON object.  Use `JArray.Parse()` (or `JToken.Parse()` if you don't know or care if the root JSON container is an array or object).  So, duplicate of [Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34690581).  Demo fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/yPeqBq

Comment: so correct please close as dup