# Reading JSON from My.Resources into String adds "vbCrLf" to my string and fails to read into JObject

Tags: json, vb.net

As the title says, I have a rather large JSON file that I have as an embedded resource into my application.

I then wish to read the JSON from the file to a string and then add it to a JObject, however everytime I do this I get an error about the path.

```
Dim value As String = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(My.Resources.JSON_Data)

Dim jsonObject As JObject = JObject.Parse(value)
```

When I check the string it seems to be added quotes and vbCrLf to the string and I feel this is causing the JObject to fall over.

Can someone point me in the right direction please.

**UPDATE**

I get the following error from the JObject.

```
'Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.'
```

Comment: If you have embedded the file and the files contains text, just read that text to a local variable. E.g., `dim json as string = My.Resources.JSON_Data`. I doubt you have stored it as a byte array, ASCII encoded. -- You see *double-double quotes* and line  feeds because this is how strings are shown in the IDE. Print it to the Console, or use the associated Viewer. -- You didn't post the actual exception.

Comment: @Jimiwhen I read it to a String it includes the vbCrLf and fails my JObject all the same.

Comment: @Lynchie Just to check, if you do `Dim value As String = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(My.Resources.JSON_Data) & "*"`, does the asterisk appear on a separate line or right at the end of the string before the CRLF?

Comment: @AndrewMorton it appears right at the VERY end

Comment: Then, maybe, you actually stored it as a Byte array instead of a string. Is that Encoding correct? Could it be UTF-8 instead? Can you post the exception? Try with `Dim jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(My.Resources.JSON_Data))`. Try also the Local encoding (`Encoding.Default`). Json.Net has no problem with lines feeds.

Comment: It was added as an existing file via Resource in the VS IDE, I didn't set it as anything to be honest.

Comment: @Lynchie That wasn't either of the options I proferred, but nvm. If you do `Dim jsonObject As JObject = JObject.Parse(value.TrimEnd())` does it work?

Comment: If you embed a file with extension `.json`, VS will store the bytes. If you chnage the extension in `.txt`, it embeds it as string. Try to save and store your text files using a specific encoding (UTF-8 possibly, which is also the default), so you have no doubts on the format after.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed my issue. Had nothing to do with the string not being returned correctly from the resource.

The whole error had to do with this

[Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690581/error-reading-jobject-from-jsonreader-current-jsonreader-item-is-not-an-object)

Sorry, appreciate anybody who attempted to assist.