# Remove character from json field name while Deserializing

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a json that has field names with '_'. However, the class where I need to map these fields doesn't have underscore. As the field names doesn't match I get the values for the mapped class as null.
I want to remove the underscore from the json fields before mapping them to the entity class. Can you please suggest which way it can be done - using *CustomConverter* or using *DefaultContractResolver* and which one be a better implementation.
example json like :

```
{\"My_UnitOfStudyStatus_Code\":\"1234\"
```

And corresponding entity class has a field called *MyUnitOfStudyStatusCode*
I need a generic solution that I can use for all my json and for mapping to all corresponding entities.

I was trying to desterilize as below

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TEntityType>(jsonString, new IgnoreUnderScoreConverter<TEntityType>()
```

Where for the converter implementation I was trying and stuck at below :

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            JObject jobject = JObject.Load(reader);
            
            var model = new T();
            //Need to rename fields for jobject 
            serializer.Populate(renamed.CreateReader(), model);

            return model;
        }
```

But I might be missing here something that I can't rename the fields that I get from jobject before they gets mapped to the entity class. Please suggest.

Comment: Is it an option to edit the entity class for changing the NamingStrategy on the class or property, as described in https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/NamingStrategyAttributes.htm?

Comment: Your TEntityType property names should be the same as json property names except underscores. How you can keep it? And does it make any sense? If spelling is broken you will lost some data. I don't think it is acceptable.

Comment: @Progman: That is not an option for me as the Entities are generated and can't modify the class.

Comment: @Serge: Yep that is the reason why I need to remove the _ for mapping purpose and keep the value intact. A possible solution is in the link - however, I am stuck at the point where I need to create the reader from the JObject : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34690581/error-reading-jobject-from-jsonreader-current-jsonreader-item-is-not-an-object

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JsonPropertyName attribute. eg:

```
[JsonPropertyName("_name")]
public string Name {get;set;}
```

this will deserialize correctly even though the property name in json has a underscore in it

Comment: Well the entity classes are autogenerated and that doesn't included these attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the work of https://www.jerriepelser.com/blog/deserialize-different-json-object-same-class/, you can use a custom [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) where you override the [`ReadJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) method, where you replace the underscores in the receiving property name to find the target property in your entity class to fill. Use the [`JObject.Properties()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Properties.htm) method to iterate over all the received properties and adjust the name accordingly. The implementation can look like this:

```
public class TestEntity
{
    public string MyUnitOfStudyStatusCode {get; set;}
    public int NormalInt {get; set;}
    public string NormalString {get; set;}
    public float AdjustedFloatName {get; set;}
}

public class MyJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
            var props = objectType.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.ToList();
        
            JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
            foreach (JProperty jp in jo.Properties())
            {
                string name = jp.Name;
                name = name.Replace("_", string.Empty);
                PropertyInfo prop = props.Single(pi => pi.CanWrite && pi.Name == name);

                object resultObject = jp.Value.ToObject(prop.PropertyType, serializer);
                object convertedResultObject = Convert.ChangeType(resultObject, prop.PropertyType);
                prop.SetValue(instance, convertedResultObject);
            }
            return instance;
        }        
        else
        {
            return reader.Value;
        }
             
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string jsonString = "{"+
            "\"My_UnitOfStudyStatus_Code\": \"1234\","+
            "\"NormalInt\": 42,"+
            "\"NormalString\": \"abc\","+
            "\"Adjusted_Float_Name\": 3.1415"+
            "}";

        TestEntity result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TestEntity>(jsonString, new MyJsonConverter());
        Console.WriteLine(result.MyUnitOfStudyStatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine(result.NormalInt);
        Console.WriteLine(result.NormalString);
        Console.WriteLine(result.AdjustedFloatName);
    }
}
```

This will generate the following output:

```
1234
42
abc
3.1415
```