# VB.NET convert JSON string with " & vbLF & " in it to parseable format?

Tags: json, vb.net, json.net

I'm using VB.NET and Newtonsoft to interact with an API via httpClient. I've run into a problem with the formatting of a string that's returned from the API. Here's an example of the return that should be JSON. It came from "copy value" for the variable. It looks like it built the string and returned that.

```
"[" & vbLf & "    {" & vbLf & "        ""count"": 7," & vbLf & "        ""headings"": [" & vbLf & "            ""name""," & vbLf & "            ""description""" & vbLf & "        ]," & vbLf & "        ""kind"": ""Detail""," & vbLf & "        ""offset"": 0," & vbLf & "        ""results"": [" & vbLf & "            [" & vbLf & "                ""PASS - Password Complexity""," & vbLf & "                ""Verifies that password complexity is enabled on the device.""" & vbLf & "            ]," & vbLf & "
```

When I try using

```
Dcontent = Await Response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync
Dim DiscJ As JObject = JObject.Parse(Dcontent)
```

it throws an error "current JsonReader item is not an object, line 1 char 1". I can output to a text box, copy it to JSONLint and it validates.

I'm drawing a blank on how to get this into a format I can parse. Any help is greatly appreciated. I've tried reading the data as a stream instead of string but that didn't change the format.

Comment: That JSON represents an Array, not an object -- You see the line breaks because the JSON is indented. Not the source of the problem

Comment: Use `JArray.Parse()` for JSON when you know the root token is an array.  Use `JToken.Parse()` when you don't know what the root token might be.  See [Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34690581) and [JSON.NET: Why Use JToken--ever?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38211719/3744182), which look to be duplicates.

Comment: Also, in my opinion creating JSON via string concatenation is unwise, you're likely to escape something wrongly.  It's much clearer to create an anonymous object, then serialize that with `JToken.FromObject()`.  In fact, looking closely, it appears you are trying to include line feeds inside a string literal.  This results in malformed JSON as line feeds must be escaped.  See [RFC 8259](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#page-8),

Comment: dbc, that is how the JSON came to me. :) I have no idea why it's being sent like that.

Comment: Oh I understand, the code shown in your question isn't how you are building the string because you aren't building the string, it's just how you generated the string in your [mcve].  If a 3rd party is sending you JSON that seems malformed, you can confirm with https://jsonlint.com/ or https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.  Then you should ask the supplier to fix their JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Although it wasn't required, I was able to use

```
DContent = DContent.Replace(vbLf, "")
```

to get rid of the line feeds. I was then able to parse my JSON using

```
Dim MyArray As JArray = JArray.Parse(DContent)
```

Thank you for pointing out it was an array instead of an object.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).